# The intervals at which $f(x) = \cos x + \sin x$ is concave up and down and $f$'s inflection point(s)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Describe the intervals at which $f(x) = \cos x + \sin x$ is concave up and down and $f$'s inflection point(s).

I totally went blank on this once I hit the analysis of second derivative, $f''(x)=-\cos x-\sin x$. I found the solution as $n\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}$ but I can't figure out how to analyze the concave up and down.

I would really appreciate an explanation not only the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the function as
$$f(x) = \sqrt2 \sin\left(x+\dfrac{\pi}4\right)$$ and the rest should follow.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance can you explain how you got to this format?

Comment: @arashaga Any expression of the form $a\cos(x) + b \sin(x)$ can be written as $r \sin(x+\theta)$, where $r = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\theta$ such that $\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{b}r$ and $\sin(\theta) = \dfrac{a}r$. You can check this by making use of the formula $$\sin(A+B) = \sin(A) \cos(B) + \cos(A) \sin(B)$$

Answer (score 0):

So you need to figure out where a function, in this case $-\cos x - \sin x$, is positive and where it's negative.  A good procedure is to figure out where it's zero first.  This partitions the real line into intervals where it's *not* zero.  Take a "test number" from each interval and plug it into your function, in this case $-\cos x - \sin x$, and see if you you get a positive or negative number.  The sign at the test point is the sign of the function on the entire interval.  Here, your function is $2\pi$-periodic, so you only need to determine how the sign behaves over one period.

Of course, the graph is concave up where $f'' > 0$ and concave down where $f'' < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The point of inflexion can be obtained by finding the value of x for which the second derivative is equal to zero. in this case

```
cosx = -sinx
```

then simply solve for x.

The intevals are just the range of x values at which the second derivative is positive or negative. If the derivative is positive, its concave up. If its nevagive concave down.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$-\cos(x)-\sin(x)= -\cos(x) \left( \tan(x) +1 \right)$$

You know where $\cos(x)$ is positive/negative and you can easily find where $ \tan(x) +1 $ is positive and negative.

Note that your function is periodic, thus it suffices to find the concavity in $[0, 2 \pi]$.